# Objective-c class naming convention

Tags: objective-c, ios

Не нашел ничего в официальной документации, как "по феншую" называть классы, если есть разделение UI по устройствам? 
Например, есть `MenuViewController` для `iPad` и отдельный для `iPhone`, пока остановился на варианте `MenuViewController_iPad` и `MenuViewController_iPhone`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я именно так как Вы описали и делаю: `MenuViewController_iPad` и `MenuViewController_iPhone`. Общий для двух классов код в таком случае прекрасно может быть вынесен в `MenuViewController`

Даже если все контроллеры создаются при помощи сторибордов или ксибов, то все-равно в сложных проектах встает проблема довольно весомых различий между отображением контента для iPad и для iPhone. `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`, конечно, способ, но применим только в случае небольших различий. В случае массивных изменений код становится не читабельным.

Answer (score 0):

можно storyboard назвать storyboard-ipad и storyboard-iphone, а вот зачем для одного и того же контроллера в разных storyboard создавать два класс. Класс нужен всего лишь один, а уже его можно подключить к контроллеру в storyboard-ipad и его же подключить в storyboard-iphone, а код в классе для ipad и iphone разделить условием UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad если у вас код разный

Comment: @Александр Садиков в проекте не используются storyboard-ы и xib-ы, это позволяет создавать кастомные view и отображать контент на разных устройствах совершенно разными способами